# apt-get does not find suggested package (perf tool)

Tags: apt, kernel

I am using performance counters (https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) on Ubuntu 13.10 x86_64. If I type `perf` I get:

```
perf not found for kernel 3.11.0-031100
You may need to install linux-tools-3.11.0-031100-generic
```

But `apt-get install ...` does not find it

```
E: Unable to locate package linux-tools-3.11.0-031100-generic
```

`uname -r` returns `3.11.0-031100-generic`, i.e., a slightly different kernel name (Ubuntu default is 3.11.0-13-generic)

How can I *by default* install the correct binaries matching the kernel (and/or what repositories do I have to add for this)?

(I know I can work around this by compiling it from the kernel sources in /tools/perf/; this works, but ideally I want to have it done automatically via apt.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have both `linux-tools` and the kernel in **the same version** or it won't work:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-tools linux-generic
sudo reboot
```

If you are using mainline kernels you must compile perf against the mainline sources, otherwise **it will not work**.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Yes, I figured that this package is quite picky (version locked or so). That's why I usually fall back to compiling it. But still, the intention of the question is to _avoid_ compilation and have apt configured (in some way) to pick the matching binaries automatically. Isn't there an easy way to do that?

Comment: @SittingAtTheBay apt only updates packages that are binaries and are in the repository, if there's no repository (in other words, if you compile it yourself) apt can't do anything for you. If you go building from source you need to go building from souces all the way.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem.
Whenever I fire perf command I got :

```
$ perf
perf_2.6.38-1208 not found
You may need to install linux-tools-2.6.38-1208
```

But actually perf was installed by installing `linux-tools` package but it was with different name `perf_2.6.38-16`.

So, I am able to use perf with `perf_2.6.38-16` command instead of `perf`.

You can create alias for `perf_2.6.38-16` with name `perf`.

Hope someone with same problem may find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and type as

```
sudo apt-get install linux-lowlatency-tools-3.11.0-11
```

Then check again.

If it fails to get you , then install these packages also and then try again

```
sudo apt-get install linux-tools-common linux-base
```

Then check again.

Comment: Does not help. I had all three packages you mention already installed (double checked just now)

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was a wrong kernel version after upgrading my system from 13.10 to 14.04.

Fixed the kernel issue by reinstalling the generic kernel package ([Wrong kernel after upgrade --- old kernel still installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449905/wrong-kernel-after-upgrade-old-kernel-still-installed)). After that, perf worked perfectly.