# Wrong kernel after upgrade --- old kernel still installed?

Tags: upgrade, kernel

I just upgraded from 13.10 to 14.04, but when I do uname -r, it says I have kernel 3.11. I want to have the default 14.04 kernel, (3.13 I believe). How can I get this?

Comment: What is the output of `uname -a` and `lsb_release -a`?

Comment: Linux MH 3.11.0-19-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 11 18:48:34 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release: 14.04
Codename: trusty

Comment: May be the same as http://askubuntu.com/questions/364156/ubuntu-13-10-kernel-still-3-8-0-31-generic? In that case my answer should work: http://askubuntu.com/a/387316/16395

Comment: Thanks to Rmano's comment. I followed the thread and did the solution that you left on it and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*This is very similar to [Ubuntu 13.10, kernel still 3.8.0-31-generic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/364156/ubuntu-13-10-kernel-still-3-8-0-31-generic) --- answering here so that this is a more generic question/answer.*

Sometime in the upgrade process the kernel meta-packages are "lost". The basic solution is to reinstall the generic kernel package:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

which should give you the correct kernel packages and headers after a:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade
```

(**obviously** if you have `-rt` or `-lowlatency` or other "flavored" kernels you have to adapt this to your case)

Sometime the system is (wrongly) convinced it has the newest kernel: in that case, try

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-generic
```