# Compiling Intel-phc says I don't have headers

Tags: kernel, compiling

Trying to follow an online tutorial ["Intel-phc with latest kernel on Ubuntu"](http://cat.feliscat.us/post/70476516134/intel-phc-with-latest-kernel-on-ubuntu). My ubuntu kernel version is 3.2.0-38-generic (Ubuntu 14.04). Following the instructions I downloaded kernel 3.14.2 from https://www.kernel.org. I was able to do all the steps except for the last two ones (make, sudo make dkms_install). I get:

```
Makefile:29: *** Kernel version not found, maybe you need to install appropriate kernel-headers or run make with KERNELSRC parameter, e.g.: make KERNELSRC=/usr/src/linux.  Stop.
```

- What am I missing here? If I understand the makefile right, it expects the compiled kernel to have the same version as my current kernel? However this is not what I read in the tutorial.

Comment: Did you installed the headers?

Comment: As I explained in my OP, yes I did install the image, headers, source *.deb files that I got by compiling kernel 3.14.2 according to the tutorial in my link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That kernel version  is strange, should be 3.13, are you sure it is not a case of [Wrong kernel after upgrade --- old kernel still installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449905/wrong-kernel-after-upgrade-old-kernel-still-installed/450008#450008)?

In that case a

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

then removing the hand-installed kernel and a reboot should solve the problem.

If you really need a different kernel and have it manually installed, you need to install the corresponding header packages, you have that explained here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds?action=show&redirect=KernelMainlineBuilds#Installing_upstream_kernels

Comment: "removing the hand-installed kernel" - which one? We have several ones here in my question. And even more importantly, how I do I remove it? I upgraded Ubuntu from 12.04 to 14.04 by the update manager before I tried installing the PHC patched kernel.

Comment: You can find the instructions to remove kernels in the same link I gave you to install the headers... Just scroll down

Comment: 1. To fix the problem of old kernel appearing after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04, I did as you suggested, rebooted - boot menu does not show an option to boot from kernel 3.13, only from 3.2; after reboot: in terminal `uname -r` still shows kernel 3.2.0. Any ideas? Or, since I want to replace the kernel altogether to a PHC-patched one, should I ignore it and focus on installing the patched kernel? 2. The link you suggested "Installing upstream kernels": it seems to me to agree to some extent with the link in my original question.

Comment: ...My link worked out up to the section "Compiling and Installing" (inclusive). That gave me 3 *.deb files: image, headers, source - I installed these files using the update manager (double-click). This corresponds to what I read in your link. Then in my link there's a final section "Phc-Intel" in which I failed (as I explained in my OP). What is this step for? and why isn't something like that mentioned in your link? 
3. And finally of course, what am I missing in order to make the final step "Phc-Intel" in my link work?