# Problem with the installation of VirtualBox

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox

I am trying to install virtualbox and make it work but it doesn't seem like I can. In the image
you can see the output.

[image: Command line output]

If I run `VBoxManage --version` I get:

```
WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
headers, most likely linux-headers-generic.

You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
4.3.10_Ubuntur93012
```

But virtualbox-dkms is already installed and at the latest version. So I tried to reinstall it and i got this:

[image: cli output 2]

Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT:

The output after reconfigure (@M.Tarun suggestion):

[image: cli output 3]

EDIT 2:

Also installed the sources as @Hmayag instructed, purged virtualbox and installed it again but I got the same problem.

Comment: Kalispera Antoni. The installer is trying to build the kernel module but fails to locate the kernel source files. The clue is `Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the kernel sources for this kernel does not seem to be installed.` Check that you have those installed. Make sure they match the running kernel version. I think `apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)` should do it.

Comment: Kalispera:). Unfortunately nothing happened. Please see my second edit.

Comment: Also installed dpkg-dev and ran the command again but no luck.

Comment: Try with `sudo` appended in front.

Comment: With no luck I meant that VirtualBox still doesn't work. Sources were succesfully installed. Now I purged VirtualBox and I am about to install it again. If something good happens I ll let you know!

Comment: Again the same. `* No suitable module for running kernel found`

Comment: You probably have a mismatch between the running kernel and the installed header. Can you add the output of `uname -a` and `dpkg -l | grep linux-headers`?

Comment: Upgrade to latest kernel. You seem to be running 3.11.

Comment: Tried it this command in Terminal `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup`

Comment: @Rmano I am facing the same problem. Here is the output https://dpaste.de/s0mi

Comment: Found solution on http://askubuntu.com/questions/582109/14-10-virtualbox-no-suitable-module-for-running-kernel-found-cannot-find-ker

Comment: Yep, same problem as http://askubuntu.com/questions/449905/wrong-kernel-after-upgrade-old-kernel-still-installed --- still happens a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to fix the problem with any other solution suggested, so I made a fresh 14.04 installation and everything is fine now.

Comment: That's the one thing I did not want to hear 

Comment: This solution is king

Answer (score 70):

Basically after you install those two packages you also need to do the reconfiguration:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms
sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox
sudo modprobe vboxdrv
```

And to fix eth0:

```
sudo modprobe vboxnetflt
```

Comment: please see the edit

Comment: works fine, thanks! Vagrant 1.7.2; VirtualBox 4.3.10; Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: How above commands will deploy for centOS

Comment: If you still have problems make sure that [UEFI secure boot is disabled](http://askubuntu.com/a/762255/323990).

Comment: I had issues with `virtualbox-dkms` support after the kernel upgrade and ended up with installation of the latest version of [VirtualBox from the official website](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) site.

Comment: The line `sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox` might be superfluous, I didn’t need it.

Comment: `elect@elect-NUC8i5BEK:~/Downloads$ sudo modprobe vboxdrv
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vboxdrv': Operation not permitted
`

Comment: I had to restart to see the changes after following these commands

Answer (score 17):

I solved this problem by following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me on ubuntu 14.04 after a dist upgrade somehow linux headers changed

Comment: This helped me. I was able to fix with: ``sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r` `` and then `sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms`. Thanks!

Comment: @stitakis your comment should be an answer so I could upvote i properly

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the problem is that you have booted the 3.11 kernel while the dpkg-reconfigure expects a 3.13 kernel. That's why you get the message 'no suitable module for the running kernel'.

Be sure to update your bootloader.

In my case the bootloader is updated from another OS (Debian) and booting to that and running `sudo update-grub` solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I used [the vendor’s official guide for Debian-based Linux distributions](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads#Debian-basedLinuxdistributions):

```sh
printf 'deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian %s contrib\n' "$(lsb_release -cs)" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list

wget -qO- https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox{,_2016}.asc | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get purge virtualbox
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.0 dkms
```

Comment: worked for me as well!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue was having virtualbox-4.1 installed alongside virtualbox-4.2. Once I uninstalled 4.1, I could run `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup` and `sudo modprobe vboxdrv` just fine, as well as start VMs.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the version of gcc your are using. I was facing the same problem of virtualbox kernel compilation.
I fixed the issue using this post https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12467

You probably are using a outdated version of gcc that is different of the gcc used by the Linux kernel.

Check the default version your are using :

```
gcc -v
```

Mine is gcc version 4.4.7 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.7-8ubuntu1)

And the gcc version your kernel was compiled with

```
dmesg | more
[    0.000000] Linux version 3.13.0-83-generic (buildd@lgw01-55) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #127-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 11 00:25:37 UTC 2016 (Ubuntu 3.13.0-83.127-generic 3.13.11-ckt35)
```

or with

```
dpkg -l gcc
```

If the gcc versions are different like on my system, switch your default gcc compiler

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
```

then virtualbox-dkms installation should works fine

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install virtualbox-dkms
```

Answer (score 0):

The clue is here: Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
headers, most likely linux-headers-generic.

Since you have the first, it must still want the second.

`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic`

Then make sure everything is up to date.

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: Sorry just forgot to write that I have them too. `linux-headers-generic is already the newest version.` is the output when i try to install them.

Comment: Thank you, I added that information to your question to insure that you get accurate answers

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I found that the source of the problem is most probably that I'm using a custom kernel.

Downloading the latest .deb package from virtualbox.org, and installing it by `dpkg -i` has solved the problem in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on ubuntu 19.04 disco. I could solve it by disabling secure boot (via BIOS).

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```