# VBox on 14.04: Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox

> **Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)**
>
> The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or
>   there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please reinstall the
>   kernel module by executing
>
> '/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup'
>
> as root. If it is available in your distribution, you should install
>   the DKMS package first. This package keeps track of Linux kernel
>   changes and recompiles the vboxdrv kernel module if necessary.

This is a familiar message to everyone that uses Virtual Box. This "bug" has been popping up every few months at least since 11.10. I got it today for the first time on 14.04 and unfortunately the [classical solution](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1885936) of re-installing `virtualbox-dkms` is not having any effect:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-dkms
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms
```

What could be the reason for this old fix to fail?

**Update**: In the comments user bain makes reference to an old thread that apparently reports to the same problem. While the error message is similar, on Ubuntu 14.04 this issue seems to have a different nature, unrelated to the `virtualbox-dkms` package. For instance, on Ubuntu 14.04 the `virtualbox` package is up to date:

```
$ sudo apt-cache policy virtualbox
virtualbox:
  Installed: 4.3.10-dfsg-1
  Candidate: 4.3.10-dfsg-1
  Version table:
 *** 4.3.10-dfsg-1 0
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Try the answers in the linked question. Make sure all updates are in place (`apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade`) then uninstall virtualbox (`apt-get purge virtualbox*`) and re-install.

Comment: Hi bain. The question you link is over 3 years old, referring to older Ubuntu versions where this problem had different solutions.

Comment: Did you try to just run the command suggested in the error message? If yes, what happened?

Comment: Hi fkraiem, the result has always been "File not found". It has been like this since 11.10.

Comment: Please reopen this question. Right now there is no viable solution for Ubuntu 14.04.Thank you.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa I fail to see the reasoning in reopening this.  If this is a bug that needs addressed, file it as a bug, and keep this closed as a thousand open questions with no resolution is detrimental - assuming that a fix comes through then perhaps we can reopen it then.

Comment: That is a great logic you have there Thomas. If the question remains closed how can a new fix be posted by someone else?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

The fix for 14.04 is indeed different, but not that different:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
sudo apt-get remove --purge virtualbox-dkms
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms
```

The `install virtualbox-dkms` command was actually failing applying the 13.10 fix. By fully purging the package things got back to normal.

**Update** [17-01-2015]: In the latest iteration of this bug a restart to the system is required between the `apt-get remove` command and the second `apt-get install`.

**Update** [07-02-2016]: This fix is [reportedly functional](https://askubuntu.com/questions/498900/vbox-on-14-04-kernel-driver-not-installed-rc-1908/499040?noredirect=1#comment1084320_499040) on Ubuntu 15.10.

**Update** [29-09-2016]: This fix is [also functional on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/498900/vbox-on-14-04-kernel-driver-not-installed-rc-1908/499040?noredirect=1#comment1315833_499040).

Comment: Are these commands run in the VM or on the host?

Comment: It is all in the host. This is a problem with VirtualBox itself.

Comment: Does not work for me.  Error during installation of virtualbox-dkms: 
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-4.0.9-040009-generic is not supported...

Comment: @hako how did you get a 4.x kernel on 14.04?

Comment: It turned out that my version 4.09 of Linux could not run with virtualbox, so I changed to v4.16 after reading somewhere that it would play well with virtualbox. That did it.

Comment: I downloaded the v4 kernel deb (3 files) from  http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4... and installed with
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.1.6*.deb linux-image-4.1.6*.deb

Comment: I get an error :
Building only for 3.19.0-33-generic
Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the
kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
 * Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules     [ OK ] 
 * Starting VirtualBox kernel modules     * No suitable module for running kernel found     [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript virtualbox, action "restart" failed.

Comment: I had the same issue on Ubuntu 15.10, and i tried this fix, it works.!

Comment: Does not work for me with 16.04.

Comment: Overkill, if you have dkms installed you were probably running virtualbox and just need to rebuild the kernel module. See  suggested duplicates at the top.

Comment: For me the REAL problem turned out to be boot-efi which is the default on the ubuntu/kubuntu-14.04 install.    After removing virtualbox-dkms & reinstalling it, I got a pop-up about boot-efi running in "secure" mode will not allow these drivers to load.....soooo, the thing rebooted in MOK, and with MOK I DISABLED efi-boot's secure mode.   ALL IS NOW WELL.

Comment: This worked for me, with the caveat of rebooting after sudo apt-get remove (I did not try anything else, though).

Comment: Worked for me on 16.04, but only with the system restart as described in the Update section.

Comment: It worked for me on 14.04

Comment: Works on 16.04 if disabled Secure Boot from UEFI in BIOS.

Comment: Worked on 17.04 with system restart.

Comment: did not work with LInux Mint 18.2 Cinnamon

Comment: Instead of complete reinstall of `virtualbox-dkms`, you can just reconfigure it: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms`. https://askubuntu.com/a/465455/250300

Comment: Is there a **permanent** fix to this issue, so that I do not have to re-fix every kernel update?

Comment: @Aaron Franke I opnened [a thread on this issue](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1885936) at the Ubuntu Forums in 2011. That thread and this question together have harnessed almost half a million views. Apparently, no one is interested in fixing this for good. In any case, with emerging technologies like Docker, the relevance of VBox is waning.

Comment: @flyingdrifter This solution is not supposed to work on Mint. It is only for the Ubuntu distribution.