# Virtualbox kernel driver on 14.04 not installed

Tags: virtualbox

I tried this method,
[VBox on 14.04, Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/534290/vbox-on-14-04-kernel-driver-not-installed-rc-1908)

As soon as I entered this line, `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup`, I get this error on the terminal, `sudo: /etc/init.d/vboxdrv: command not found`.

How do I fix this.

Comment: Stupid question, but have you install virtualbox packages?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you "enter this line"? if you like to install virtualbox on 14.04, just install dkms and linux-header-generic and afterwards add the oracle repository and install from it, the kernel drivers will be installed during the process of installing virtualbox:

Install prerequesits:

```
sudo apt-get install dkms linux-headers-generic
```

Add repository key:

```
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

Add repository to sources list:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian trusty contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle.list'
```

Install virtualbox:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.0
```

you could also install virtualbox-4.3 or virtualbox-4.2 instead of 5.0 if you wish.

Have Fun.