# Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908) -- Again

Tags: drivers, kernel

After I read the solution in [VBox on 14.04: Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/498900/vbox-on-14-04-kernel-driver-not-installed-rc-1908/499040#499040?newreg=d08ca45c497848d8974bf0b39250ae10)

I got following error after install ...

```
No suitable module for running kernel found
invoke-rc.d: initscript virtualbox, action "restart" failed.
```

What can I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix 'modprobe vboxdrv' error in virtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/920689/how-to-fix-modprobe-vboxdrv-error-in-virtualbox) and [Virtualbox Kernel driver not installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41118/)

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me with below commands for Ubuntu 14.04

Download the virtual box https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

Remove dkms, since I installed several times this helped.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge virtualbox-dkms
sudo dpkg -i Downloads/virtualbox-5.0_5.0.8-103449-Ubuntu-trusty_amd64.deb 
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```