# How can I fix this 'modprobe vboxdrv' error in VirtualBox? ERROR: could not insert 'vboxdrv': Required key not available

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox

I install `virtualBox` on Ubuntu 16.04, but after install and create new virtual Host shows this error:

> Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)
>
> The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please install virtualbox-dkms package and load the kernel module by executing
>
> ```
> modprobe vboxdrv
> ```
>
> as root. If it is available in your distribution, you should install the
> DKMS package first. This package keeps track of Linux kernel changes and   recompiles the vboxdrv kernel module if necessary.
>
> where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.

When I try to run `sudo modprobe vboxdrv`, I get this error:

```
$ sudo modprobe vboxdrv
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vboxdrv': Required key not available
```

How can I address this `modprobe vboxdrv` error?

Comment: Do you try ‘sudo modprobe vboxdrv‘ ?

Comment: See this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/920618/cant-make-machines-in-virtualbox?noredirect=1#comment1453750_920618) is exactly the same just a few hours ago. Maybe one of the comments will help you aswell since Jimmi hasn't said yet what helped him.

Comment: @AliRazmdideh OP answered your question in this comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/920689/how-to-fix-modprobe-vboxdrv-error-in-virtualbox#comment1453951_920713

Answer (score 90, accepted):

As the first step run this command:

```
sudo modprobe vboxdrv
```

If it's not helpful run these commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r) virtualbox-dkms dkms
```

Then **reboot** your system and after reboot run this command:

```
sudo modprobe vboxdrv
```

And if it doesn't work you must **disable Secure Boot** in your BIOS/UEFI settings because Secure Boot prevents unsigned modules from being loaded.

Comment: Hi, After run `sudo modprobe vboxdrv`, show this error: `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vboxdrv': Required key not available`

Comment: @mySun Is your problem solved ? If my answer is not be helpful , please read this post instructions to solve `Required key not available` issue : https://askubuntu.com/questions/760671/could-not-load-vboxdrv-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04-and-i-want-to-keep-secur

Comment: I read this post and find my problem :-) Thank you.

Comment: I didn't need to reboot but your apt install method did work.

Comment: What's the best way to automate it at boot? Should I put it into /usr/lib/modules-load.d?

Comment: Or rather in /etc/modules. Does it make sense to do it? Does this module consume a lot of resources? I don't need VirtualBox every day, so it will only make sense if it's an inexpensive operation.

Comment: this worked for me +1

Comment: not works, the first try `modprobe: FATAL: Module vboxdrv not found in directory /lib/modules/5.0.0-23-generic`

Comment: This worked and solved my vagrant issue after updating my pc to ubuntu 19.10

Comment: Is it possible that I should not do that after each restart? I put the `vboxdrv` insinde `/etc/modules` but I have to run `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r) virtualbox-dkms dkms` each time

Answer (score 4):

1. Uninstall virtualbox-dkms and its configurations by running the below commands:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-dkms
   sudo apt-get remove --purge virtualbox-dkms
   ```
2. Install Linux headers and Linux image by running the below command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -y linux-headers-amd64 linux-image-amd64
   ```
3. Install virtualbox-dkms

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -y virtualbox-dkms
   ```

Comment: My system cannot find `linux-headers-amd64` or `linux-image-amd64
`
Trying `apt dist-upgrade` instead.

Comment: linux header installation has to be generic `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r) virtualbox-dkms dkms`

Answer (score 2):

In my case it has to do with UEFI being active.
In that case, unsigned kernel modules like `vboxdrv` aren't loaded.

More info here:
[Could not load 'vboxdrv' after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 (and I want to keep secure boot)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760671/could-not-load-vboxdrv-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04-and-i-want-to-keep-secur)

Answer (score 0):

Like @david.perez exposed, it can be solved by disabling the UEFI Secure Boot:

1. do 'Power Off / Restart'
2. at the very first screen, select 'UEFI settings'
3. in the Bios interface, browse until 'UEFI' tab
4. change 'Enabled' to 'Disabled', save and exit

Answer (score 0):

I'm using 20.04 and I followed the steps from Zanna described above.

Then I got this error when trying to execute the last command:

Error: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert ‘vboxdrv’: Operation not permitted

I followed this guide to fix the permission error:

https://crazytechgo.com/modprobe-error-could-not-insert-vboxdrv-operation-not-permitted/