# Problem with VirtualBox and vboxdrv

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

When I try to lunch my virtual machine, it gives me this error:
The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up correctly. Please reinstall virtualbox-dkms package and load the kernel module by executing

'modprobe vboxdrv'

as root.

If your system has EFI Secure Boot enabled you may also need to sign the kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.

where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.

When I write `modprobe vboxdrv`, it gives me this output: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vboxdrv': Operation not permitted

Any suggestions?

when I search for vboxdrv I can't find it on my computer, but also udo vboxconfig seems not to be in sbin folder.

There is also another message about the kernel problem, that is this one: Failed to start LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module.

Comment: Did you try this solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/920689/how-to-fix-modprobe-vboxdrv-error-in-virtualbox ?

Comment: Read your own output carefully: It's clearly telling you what to do. Looks like you're not following it's instructions.

Comment: yes the problem is that, if I am right, there's no such vboxdrv, I can not find it in the init.d folder.