# VirtualBox 20.10 new error : WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist

Tags: virtualbox

VirtualBox has been working on this Ubuntu host for *years*.

Now after the `do-release-upgrade` from 20.04 to 20.10 it is having a trouble:

```
 sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 linux-headers-5.8.0-31-generic is already the newest version (5.8.0-31.33).
 linux-headers-5.8.0-31-generic set to manually installed.
 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
 sudo apt install virtualbox virtualbox-dkms
 [sudo] password for stephen: 
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 virtualbox is already the newest version (6.1.14-dfsg-4).
 virtualbox-dkms is already the newest version (6.1.14-dfsg-4).
 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
 stephen@acer:~$ vboxmanage list vms
 WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
      Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
      headers, most likely linux-headers-generic. 

       You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
```

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the virtualbox dkms driver? I think https://askubuntu.com/a/920713/612 may help here.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help, but this is the command I run after every kernel update: `sudo apt-get install dkms build-essential linux-headers-generic -y ; sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) -y; sudo apt install --reinstall virtualbox -y` It's pretty similar to what you've run, but you can give it a shot.

Comment: @popey The link was useful though I didn't need to rebuild. The `modprobe vboxdrv` got us to the next step and then
`sudo apt install virtualbox-ext-pack`;
`sudo modprobe vboxnetflt`;
Working now.