# Upgraded to 17.10, now VirtualBox won't work. Flying blind

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, 17.10

```
sudo modprobe vboxdrv
modprobe: FATAL: Module vboxdrv not found in directory /lib/modules/4.10.0-35-generic
```

I reinstalled dkms but I still get

> **Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)**
>
> The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please reinstall virtualbox-dkms package and load the kernel module by executing
>
> 'modprobe vboxdrv'

I ran:

```
find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -name vboxdrv.ko
```

but there was no output.

Comment: These questions might have some useful answers: [Virtualbox Kernel driver not installed](https://askubuntu.com/q/41118/301745), [VBox on 14.04: Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908) \[duplicate\]](https://askubuntu.com/q/498900/301745)

Comment: Try disabling secure boot in BIOS