# Cannot run VM VirtualBox on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, virtualbox

I am having issues trying to run Virtual Box; which are the "`appropiate headers"`??

```
WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
     Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
     headers, most likely linux-headers-generic.

     You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
```

I have installed `virtualbox-dkms` package, but I have no idea about the headers.

Also when trying to run a VM

> Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)
>
> The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please install virtualbox-dkms package and load the kernel module by executing
>
> ```
> 'modprobe vboxdrv'
> ```
>
> as root. If it is available in your distribution, you should install the DKMS package first. This package keeps track of Linux kernel changes and recompiles the vboxdrv kernel module if necessary.
>
> where: `suplibOsInit` what: `3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908)` - The support driver is not installed. On Linux, open returned ENOENT.

I cannot run `modprobe vboxdrv` (yes, I run it with `sudo`)

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vboxdrv': Operation not permitted
```

I think this is a common question but cannot find answers for Ubuntu 16.04, just outdated ones.

**UPDATE**

`linux-headers-generic` is installed but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps also try this solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/499040/512236)

Comment: I've just posted the solution (for me) of this issue [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760671/could-not-load-vboxdrv-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04-and-i-want-to-keep-secur/1199583#1199583)

Answer (score 4):

Did you try:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install --reinstall virtualbox-dkms
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

To install the headers do

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-generic
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like they are already installed so must be some other thing missing

Comment: Please also try `sudo apt install build-essential gcc make perl`

Answer (score 0):

How did you install it in the first place?
I usuall just install it with

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

which installs all required packages and builds the modules for the current kernel.
You will have to run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms
```

if you upgrade your kernel.

Hope it gives you a clue, otherwise post back.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

## Install/Check Virtualbox Driver

The installation of the Virtualbox drivers can fail for several reasons. First check if the kernel modules have been create:

```
$ ls -la /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/misc
total 696
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Mar  7 16:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root   4096 Mar  7 16:02 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 600232 Mar  7 16:02 vboxdrv.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  16204 Mar  7 16:02 vboxnetadp.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  43134 Mar  7 16:02 vboxnetflt.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  39959 Mar  7 16:02 vboxpci.ko
```

If the modules are missing run `vboxconfig` manual:

```
$ sudo vboxconfig 
## ... some output ###
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
```

`vboxconfig` will produce some useful output, if there are errors.

After that check if virtualbox is working properly with the module.

```
$ sudo vboxmanage --version
5.2.8r121009
```

Comment: `sudo vboxfonfig` - command not found)). i think that's my problem, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @nick Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @SimonSudler 20.04