# Linux kernel discrepancy 3.11 and 14.04 preventing me from using Virtualbox

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, package-management, vmware

I am trying to execute this command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package linux-headers-3.11.0-15-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'linux-headers-3.11.0-15-generic' has no installation candidate
```

===

If I run:

```
$uname -asr
3.11.0-15-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 30 17:22:01 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

It seems that I have a discrepancy at my Linux installation.
Due to this I am not able to run virtualbox and vmware.

Comment: Are you talking about the difference between 3.11 and 14.04? If yes, don't worry: 3.11 is the *Linux* version, 14.04 the *Ubuntu* version.

Comment: How did you end up with 3.11 in Trusty? Its default kernel is 3.13.

Comment: I think maybe it's time to reboot if you're still actively running a 3.11 kernel in 14.04. 3.13.0.37 is the current version of the kernel in Ubuntu 14.04. Now that 14.10 has been released, there should be an LTS kernel update to the newer kernel (3.17) coming soon.

Comment: Hi, from the synaptic I see that I have both kernels. I am new to Linux and I am not sure how I ended up here except form the fact that I first installed Ubuntu 12.04 and then I upgraded to 14. 
My main problem is to run virtual box. If I reinstall Linux on top of my current installation then is there any chance that it will fix the problem ?

Comment: Hello,this person here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/465454/problem-with-the-installation-of-virtualbox

seems to experienced similar problem to me.
I have made the upgrade but I choose to install on top of my existing Linux installation in order to keep my files and installed programs if possible. Unfortunately I see the error messages as before but simply with newer kernel numbers.
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-3.16.0-031600-lowlatency
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-3.16.0-031600-lowlatency'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem with the installation of VirtualBox](http://askubuntu.com/questions/465454/problem-with-the-installation-of-virtualbox)

Answer (score 1):

In the end I fixed this by downloading and manually installing the headers for the kernel version that `uname -r` gave me. I used [these instructions from ubuntuhandbook.org](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/08/install-upgrade-linux-kernel-3-16/).

Then I rebooted I choose advanced options in order to change to the correct kernel (from lowlatency to generic).

Finally I was able to install and use virtual box properly.

Comment: The lowlatency kernel should work too.