# Re-install VirtualBox, keep all configuration and machines

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

I had [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465454/problem-with-the-installation-of-virtualbox) and followed, quite blindly, all steps. Tha last step is, purge VirtualBox and install it again. Here comes my doubt as I have a few virtual machines configured and I don't want to loose any information. Will these machines be there after this?:

```
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

Thanks

Comment: After all steps, still I was receiving error `your kernel headers cannot be found` so I had to install headers with `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pre-installed Virtual Box virtual machines and the machine's setting which are stored in your home directory will not be affected by removing or purging the Virtual Box application.

You will be able to access them after re-installing Virtual Box just the same as before. I did this several times, not only on every major version release of Virtual Box where we need to remove the previous version to be able to upgrade.

In case you had installed the Oracle Extension Pack you will however re-install this too before you can run your VMs. Also it is recommended to also upgrade any Guest Addition we may had installed before.

Comment: It failed re-installing: `Configurando virtualbox (4.3.36-dfsg-1+deb8u1ubuntu1.14.04.1) ...
 * Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules                                                                                                      [ OK ] 
 * Starting VirtualBox kernel modules                                                                                                              * No suitable module for running kernel found`

Comment: The version of Virtual Box you tried to install apparently does not match your kernel version. See e.g. http://askubuntu.com/questions/582109/14-10-virtualbox-no-suitable-module-for-running-kernel-found-cannot-find-ker or - check your sources.list, or install the Virtual Box version matching your kernel [from Oracle](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)

Answer (score 0):

The uninstaller just removes the VB application and the drivers (kexts), it leaves your virtual machines and their settings files alone. As mpack said, it's the same as updating any other program, it updates the software but doesn't touch the documents (your VMs).