# VirtualBox Error : The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist

Tags: virtualbox, genymotion

I am trying to install virtualbox for genymotion on ubuntu 16.04. But failing everytime.

First of all I tried to install virtualbox with simple command

`sudo apt-get install virutalbox`

But, still virtual box was failing to start.

Then I searched for same error,

and I found this [Problem with the installation of VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465454/problem-with-the-installation-of-virtualbox)

I followed all the methods that are given, But didn't help.

I am positing the screenshots of all the commands that I have tried.

When I run `virtualbox` in terminal, it pops-up a new window for virtualbox , but still it gives warning in terminal that some character device `/dev/vboxdrv` is missing.And without this tool I will not be able to start virtualbox. 
 [Please see in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUSNn.png)

I am sure that I had appropriate `linux-headers-4.4`

I tried to install `virtualbox-dkms package` , but didn't help.
[See this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeN79.png)

I have taken more screenshots, but i can't upload them.

Any help will be appriciated. Thank you.

---

**EDIT 1**
This is what my terminal shows when I type "virtualbox" in terminal

> WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
>        Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
>        headers, most likely linux-headers-generic.
>
> You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.

Comment: well, maybe you should take a look at `journalctl -u virtualbox.service`. And just run `apt install linux-headers-generic` and `dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms`. Do not *think* that it is correct, **ensure** it.

Comment: @LittleByBlue , I am not able to upload screenshots here, Can you please go to this link.. 

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_00hjm0ktXyS3NKbE9mQW4tdmc

Comment: Copy and paste what you need in your post from your terminal.

Comment: @George Please look at edit, And thank you for replying :)

Comment: so what errors did  `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic virtualbox-ose-dkms` then `sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms` and `sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtual box` return?

Comment: @ArduinoSentinel , For the first command it shows error, "Unable to locate package virtualbox-ose-dkms"  .  For second command it shows "invoke-rc.d: initscript virtualbox, action "restart" failed." ... I am noob, I don't know what is happening :|

Comment: @NeerPatel well, take a look at your output. Your installation fails, because `virtualbox-ext-pack` fails to download additional files. Try to skip the Installation of  `virtualbox-ext-pack`, it is not necessary.

Comment: @LittleByBlue , okay... Then does that mean I just need to install virtualbox without any extra packages ???

Comment: Please follow @LittleByBlue instructions don't install with _extension pack_ then download the right one for your virtualbox version and add and build accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether you have meanwhile resolved this issue, but I just struck the same problem.  For me the key lay in:

> ┌────────────────────────────────────────────┤ Configuring Secure Boot
>   ├────────────────────────────────────────────┐  │
>   │  │ Your system has UEFI Secure Boot enabled.
>   │  │
>   │  │ UEFI Secure Boot is not compatible with the use of third-party
>   drivers.                                           │  │
>   │  │ The system will assist you in toggling UEFI Secure Boot. To
>   ensure that this change is being made by you as an    │  │ authorized
>   user, and not by an attacker, you must choose a password now and then
>   use the same password after      │  │ reboot to confirm the change.
>   │  │
>   │  │ If you choose to proceed but do not confirm the password upon
>   reboot, Ubuntu will still be able to boot on your   │  │ system but
>   the Secure Boot state will not be changed.
>   │  │
>   │  │ If Secure Boot remains enabled on your system, your system may
>   still boot but any hardware that requires          │  │ third-party
>   drivers to work correctly may not be usable.
>   │  │
>   │  │                                                      
>   │  │
>   │ 
>   └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

Once UEFI Secure Boot was disabled DKMS built & loaded the driver just fine.

Comment: thanks a lot for beautiful explanation. well, I resolved this issue by consulting one of my Tech Genius friend. I have no idea what magic he did...