# Virtualbox - The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist

Tags: virtualbox

I installed virtualbox on my ubuntu 16.04 machine.But I am unable to run it. When I run

> sudo virtualbox

It gives me the following result

> WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
>        Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
>        headers, most likely linux-headers-generic.

```
 You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
```

I ran the command to install the virtualbox-dkms but it gave the following result

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   virtualbox-dkms is already the newest version (5.0.40-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2).
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 149 not upgraded.

I searched around and found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866442/virtualbox-error-the-character-device-dev-vboxdrv-does-not-exist) but I did not understand it and hence it could not help me. Any suggestions what I should do to get the virtualbox running ?

Comment: Should `virtualbox` be run with sudo? Please run without sudo!

Comment: Running it as non super user still gives the same result

Comment: Look at this https://stegard.net/2016/10/virtualbox-secure-boot-ubuntu-fail/