# Ubuntu 15.10 Video card crash

Tags: ati, display, screen, gpu

ubuntu boots just fine but sometimes the display just freezes.
So i'm guessing it's a GPU problem.

My graphics card is a r9 390x and works just fine on windows.

Is there something i can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to check if the graphic card driver is updated?

Go to **System settings -> Hardware -> Additional drivers**. Check if there is something to update. You can also update via terminal. Check [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/524142/how-to-update-all-driver-software-via-terminal).

If it doesn't work and you still have the problem, try  [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top).

Comment: Sadly everything is up to date as far as i can tell.

Comment: Well, have you tried the 2nd link?

Comment: Yes. The accepted answer seems to be about restarting if i got it right. I can restart and boot just fine. There's another answer about video card drivers but i think i have them up to date, unless there's some place where i can get more recent ones. ( the only thing i've done is check for updates through the GUI )

Comment: Usually, the updates you see in GUI are the same in the command line, so no need to check in the terminal for updates

Comment: I guess i'll take a look and the logs and possibly create a bug report in the proper place.