# slow internet download on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: networking, 15.10

I installed on Ubuntu 15.10 on a fresh computer, and on the first 2 days, the wifi download speed was normal (torrent download was about 2mb/s).

But today, my download speed is no more than 100kb/s. I've tried most of the solutions posted online, but it doesn't seem to work.

I've just reformatted my computer and reinstalled Ubuntu 15.10 again, but the problem still persists.

I've also reset the modem as well.

What should I do?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your network drivers 
[How to I update Ralink 5390 adapter driver via terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/524142/how-to-update-all-driver-software-via-terminal)

Check the seeders/leechers for the torrent you are downloading.

try changing the trackers.

Try port forwarding (most likely the problem )

http://www.pcworld.com/article/244314/how_to_forward_ports_on_your_router.html