# Upgrading Linux Kernel 3.11 to 3.13 for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: grub2, upgrade, kernel

When I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04, apparently my kernel was supposed to upgrade from 3.11 to 3.13. Unfortunately, the kernel upgrade did not complete. As a result, I have several files for 3.13, but am still running 3.11. I've decided the best thing for me to do is to complete the kernel upgrade.

Specifically, when I look at the linux packages I have installed, I see:

```
me@Bedrock1:~/Downloads/cudaDownloads$ dpkg -l | grep "linux-" | cut -d " " -f 3
gcc-4.8-powerpc-linux-gnu-base
linux-firmware
linux-headers-3.13.0-29
linux-headers-3.13.0-29-generic
linux-headers-3.13.0-30
linux-headers-3.13.0-30-generic
linux-headers-3.13.0-32
linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic
linux-headers-3.13.0-34
linux-headers-3.13.0-34-generic
linux-headers-3.13.0-35
linux-headers-3.13.0-35-generic
linux-headers-3.13.0-36
linux-headers-3.13.0-36-generic
linux-headers-3.13.0-37
linux-headers-3.13.0-37-generic
linux-headers-3.13.0-39
linux-headers-3.13.0-39-generic
linux-headers-generic
linux-image-3.11.0-23-generic
linux-image-3.8.0-33-generic
linux-image-extra-3.11.0-23-generic
linux-image-extra-3.8.0-33-generic
linux-libc-dev:amd64
linux-sound-base
linux-source
linux-source-3.13.0
syslinux-common
syslinux-legacy

and, when I look in my boot directory, I see:

me@Bedrock1:~$ ls /boot
abi-3.11.0-23-generic         memtest86+.bin
abi-3.8.0-33-generic          memtest86+.elf
config-3.11.0-23-generic      memtest86+_multiboot.bin
config-3.8.0-33-generic       System.map-3.11.0-23-generic
grub                          System.map-3.8.0-33-generic
initrd.img-3.11.0-23-generic  vmlinuz-3.11.0-23-generic
initrd.img-3.8.0-33-generic   vmlinuz-3.8.0-33-generic
```

It looks as though I can use apt-get/synaptic to install linux-image-3.13 and linux-image-extra-3.13, but I can't find downloads for any of the files in my /boot directory. Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

Should I expect installation of the correct packages to update GRUB files as necessary, or will I need to read up on that before I start booting into the 3.13 kernel?

Are there any other files I should be checking for?

Is there an obvious reason why my kernel didn't manage to update completely to 3.13? If so, do I need to compensate for it?

Comment: Seems a bad case of http://askubuntu.com/questions/449905/wrong-kernel-after-upgrade-old-kernel-still-installed --- try to `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-generic`

Comment: @Rmano - This worked. I'd flag this link as the answer, but since it's a comment, all I can do is upvote.

Comment: You can upvote the main question --- I have slightly updated it. Then I will mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: @Rmano - OK, I've just upvoted the original question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Currently on Ubuntu 14.04, my kernel version is 3.16.0-25.
Try installing this version if you want the latest one.

Have you tried simply the following commands? The first one checks the updates and the second one installs them ?

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

What is the output?

Comment: Yes, I tried those and sudo apt dist-upgrade, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Some installer may prompt for separate boot partition, and if that is small size then it can become full and fail to build new kernel/initramfs. Check this with df?