# Can't install Virtualbox on 15.04

Tags: virtualbox

I was using Ubuntu 14.10 on my setup and I had Virtualbox running fine.

Then my OCZ Vertex 2 (SSD) died unexpectedly and I had to reinstall everything.

But, because the Intel Graphics Drivers weren't installing on Ubuntu 14.10 (February 2015), I chose to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. What a surprise that the new April 2015 drivers will ONLY install on Ubuntu 14.10! So I then upgraded to Ubuntu 14.10 and, after installing the drivers I updated to 15.04.

Why I did this introduction? Because *maybe* something wrong happened during the update, especially with the kernel update.

When I install Virtualbox I get this error:

```
Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMS.

Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 3.19.7-031907-generic cannot be found.

Please install the linux-headers-3.19.7-031907-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
 ...failed!
  (Failed, trying without DKMS)
Recompiling VirtualBox kernel modules ...failed!
```

Before, the kernel was like 3.16, I manually updated to 3.19.7, but it can't find kernel headers:  what can I do?

Comment: Check if you don't have a case of http://askubuntu.com/questions/449905/wrong-kernel-after-upgrade-old-kernel-still-installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to install the headers first:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

you have to recompile the kernel module and install it by

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

If some error appears then try this solution:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-ose
```

This will take care of dependencies like the kernel headers which is included in the package linux-headers-generic

Comment: it says linux-headers-3.19.7-031907-generic is not available (output not in english, my translation)

Comment: `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` output opf this command?

Comment: Il pacchetto linux-headers-3.19.7-031907-generic non ha versioni disponibili, ma è nominato da un altro
pacchetto. Questo potrebbe indicare che il pacchetto è mancante, obsoleto
oppure è disponibile solo all'interno di un'altra sorgente

E: Il pacchetto "linux-headers-3.19.7-031907-generic" non ha candidati da installare

Comment: Write in English please

Comment: what happens if you run this `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-ose`?

Comment: I manually installed kernel 4.0.1-040001-lowlatency and the sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup  command finally worked (before it said kernel headers not found)

Comment: Then you solve your problem?