# Install Virtualbox on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: virtualbox

I try to install the Virtualbox software following the directions from the Oracle's website: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

When I start Virtualbox is displayed to me the following message:

> The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
>   available for the current kernel (4.4.0-22-generic) or it failed to
>   load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by: sudo
>   /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup.

Additionally,I execute the directions from this answer: 
[Can't install Virtualbox on 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/620921/cant-install-virtualbox-on-15-04)

but my problem is not solved. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi. See if the answer in [this question](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) helps. It has a similar error message to yours.

Comment: Thanks, but the link which you posted is the same with the directions of the Oracle's website which I have referred in my question.

Comment: Sorry. I pasted the wrong link! Try [this link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282265/starting-virtualbox-kernel-modules-failed).

Answer (score 27):

I don't think I had to do any of that on Ubuntu > 16.04. I would try the version in Ubuntu repositories. Simply install it from the `Ubuntu Software` or run the command:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

You might want to undo any changes to the software sources.list that you have done first.

Answer (score 3):

Remove older version of virutalbox if it's installed in the system

```
sudo apt remove virtualbox
```

Add PPA to sources.list

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add this file to the end of the file and do Ctrl+X to exit `nano`

```
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial contrib
```

Fetch the GPG key

```
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

Install the package

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install virtualbox-5.1
```

Comment: I'm getting  Forbidden [IP: 103.123.234.254 80]