# How to recover from a botched attempt to clean /boot, incomplete kernel/drivers

Tags: drivers, kernel

Ubuntu 14.0.4 generated an error trying to update. Turns out my `/boot` partition was full.  I ran a command to remove the old kernels, something like this:

```
dpkg --get-selections|grep 'linux-image*'|awk '{print $1}'|egrep -v "linux-image-$(uname -r)|linux-image-generic" |while read n;do apt-get -y remove $n;done
```

but I neglected to reboot before doing this and test things, as a result, it cleared `/boot` but generated a few errors.  I then ran aptitude update/upgrade.  Upon rebooting Ubuntu comes up but it's really slow, has no network connectivity, and does not recognize the USB wireless mouse.  It looks like various system drivers are now not recognized.

How can I repair this installation?  The system will boot but it's obvious the drivers are not there for the network or USB mouse and probably other things.  Can I restore the kernel and undo this to some degree?

Comment: Try http://askubuntu.com/a/450008/16395  - The last paragraph. Could work or not...

Comment: after running this

    sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-generic 

produced the following errors

   `dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-52-generic (--configure)`

    `package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-52generic is not ready for configuration`

    `cannot configure (current status 'half-installed')`

    `dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic`

    `linux-image-generic depends on linus-image-extra-3.13.0-52.86) ...`
    `No apport report written becuase the error indicates its a previous error ....`

Comment: `dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure): dependency problems - leaving unconfigured`
    Setting up linux-headers-3.13.0-52 (3.13.0-52-86) ...
    No apport report written becuase the error indicates its a previous error ....

Answer (score 2):

Here was the solution.  Thanks to Rmano for pointing me in the right direction.

I ran `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-generic` and it generated an error, so I then ran
`sudo apt-get -f install`
and then re-ran
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-generic`

and restored the system.  Everything is back!