# Latest kernel running?

Tags: kernel

Using Ubuntu 16.04.

uname -r gives 3.13.0-77-generic, but installed latest kernel seems to be 4.4.0-62-generic, so what kernel am I running? Or, how to force to use the latest installed stable kernel?

Comment: Are you on a VPS?

Comment: Check if it is the same as http://askubuntu.com/questions/449905/wrong-kernel-after-upgrade-old-kernel-still-installed

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with installing the LILO boot and followed its instructions, but booting time are long. Kernel 4.4.0-62-generic is now running in my personal computer. I guess this is a temporary fix for me, all is well, thank you.